# Install xdebug with php5.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xdebug, php-5.3

I had such a problem can not install on Ubuntu xdebug with php 5.3, 5.4 is not suitable because the server on Linux ATL licensed.

Comment: I think if you have any installation log or the actual error message, it can be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial about "How to configure XDebug in Ubuntu" could be useful.
 https://phptechnologytutorials.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/how-to-configure-xdebug/